# How to restart same Activity?

Tags: java, android

If i have 10 EditText and the user enter only in 5 then i exit my app on click the onBackPressed Button without submit the EditText data which is entering , and then when i restart my app i want to same activity on start up.Thanks to appriceat.

```
public class Registration_Form extends Activity {
EditText et_CompanyName;
EditText et_EmployeeName;
EditText et_CompanyWebsite;
EditText et_ContactNumber;
EditText et_Email_Id;

Button btnSubmit;
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
SQLiteDatabase db;

 RadioGroup radioGroup_FinancialYaer;
 RadioButton radioButton_FinancialYaer; 
 String strFinancialYear;
 String appWidgetId = null;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.registration_details);

    SharedPreferences prefs =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
    boolean alldataSaved=prefs.getBoolean("SecondRun",false);

    et_CompanyName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_CompanyName);
    et_EmployeeName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_EmployeeName);
    et_CompanyWebsite = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_CompanyWebSite);
    et_ContactNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_ConatctNo);
    et_Email_Id = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_EmailId);



    et_CompanyName.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(!hasFocus)
            {
                edit.putString("Company_Name"+appWidgetId,et_CompanyName.getText().toString());
                edit.commit();
            }
        }
    });


    et_EmployeeName.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(!hasFocus)
            {
                edit.putString("Employee_Name"+appWidgetId,et_EmployeeName.getText().toString());
                edit.commit();
            }
        }
    });



    et_CompanyWebsite.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(!hasFocus)
            {
                edit.putString("Company_Website"+appWidgetId,et_CompanyWebsite.getText().toString());
                edit.commit();
            }
        }
    });


    et_ContactNumber.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(!hasFocus)
            {
                edit.putString("Contact_Number"+appWidgetId,et_ContactNumber.getText().toString());
                edit.commit();
            }
        }
    });



    et_Email_Id.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(!hasFocus)
            {
                edit.putString("Email_Id"+appWidgetId,et_Email_Id.getText().toString());
                edit.commit();
            }
        }
    });






      SharedPreferences settings=getSharedPreferences("prefs",0); 
      boolean firstRun=settings.getBoolean("firstRun",false);

      if(firstRun==false)//if running for first time 

      {
          SharedPreferences.Editor editor=settings.edit();
          editor.putBoolean("firstRun",true); 
          editor.commit();
          //execute your code for first time
      } 

      else 
      { 
          if(alldataSaved == false)
          {
              SharedPreferences.Editor editor=prefs.edit();
              editor.putBoolean("SecondRun",true); 
              editor.commit();
              Log.e("Second"," Steps !!!!");
          }
          else
          {
              Intent iSubmit = new Intent(Registration_Form.this,Employee_List.class);
              startActivity(iSubmit);
              finish();
              //Default Activity startActivity(a); 
          }

      }

    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    databaseHelper.onOpen(db);


    radioGroup_FinancialYaer = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroupFinanncialYear);


    btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit);
    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            final String stringEmail_Id = et_Email_Id.getText().toString()
                    .trim();

            final String stringCompanyWebsite = et_CompanyWebsite.getText()
                    .toString().trim();

            if ((et_CompanyName.getText().toString().isEmpty()))
            {
                et_CompanyName.setError("Field Can Not Be Empty !");
            }

            else if (!et_CompanyName.getText().toString().trim()
                    .matches("[a-zA-Z ]+"))
            {
                et_CompanyName.setError("Accept Alphabets Only.");
            }

            else if ((et_EmployeeName.getText().toString().isEmpty()))
            {
                et_EmployeeName.setError("Field Can Not Be Empty !");
            }

            else if (!et_EmployeeName.getText().toString().trim()
                    .matches("[a-zA-Z ]+"))
            {
                et_EmployeeName.setError("Accept Alphabets Only.");
            }

            else if ((et_CompanyWebsite.getText().toString().isEmpty()))
            {
                et_CompanyWebsite.setError("Field Can Not Be Empty !");
            }

            else if (!isValidUrl(stringCompanyWebsite))
            {
                et_CompanyWebsite.setError("Invalid URL");
            }

            else if ((et_ContactNumber.getText().toString().isEmpty()))
            {
                et_ContactNumber.setError("Field Can Not Be Empty !");
            }

            else if (!isValidEmail(stringEmail_Id))
            {
                et_Email_Id.setError("Invalid Email");
            }

            else

            {
                String stringCompanyName = et_CompanyName.getText()
                        .toString().trim();
                String stringContactNumber = et_ContactNumber.getText()
                        .toString().trim();
                String stringEmployeeName = et_EmployeeName.getText()
                        .toString().trim();


                int selectedId = radioGroup_FinancialYaer.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                Log.e("selectedId "," = " + selectedId);
                radioButton_FinancialYaer = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
                strFinancialYear = radioButton_FinancialYaer.getText().toString().trim();
                Log.e("strRadioButton "," = " + strFinancialYear);


                databaseHelper.insertRegstrationDetails(stringCompanyName,
                        stringEmployeeName, stringCompanyWebsite,
                        stringContactNumber, stringEmail_Id, strFinancialYear);
                System.out.println("Data Inserted Successfully !!! ");

                Intent iSubmit = new Intent(Registration_Form.this,Staff_Employee_Details.class);
                startActivity(iSubmit);
                finish();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you want that when you restart app at that time those four edittext should be filled?

Comment: Use SharedPreferences ..

Comment: @Kalpesh Lakhani : Yah right.

Comment: @Kedarnath : But how to use.

Comment: @Kedarnath : I used Shared Preferences for Activity running for first time.

Comment: This may be what you are looking for: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#SavingActivityState

Comment: do you want to same activity with unsaved data? I mean previous data.

Comment: @ user1688181 : Yah actually i want this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sharedPreference for this. you can save the value of each edittext in one sharedprefrerece (with unique key for each edittext and set values at the time of focus change. see example:)

```
EditText txtEdit= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittxt);

 txtEdit.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(!hasFocus)
           //do job here when Edittext lose focus 
          //means save value here
    }
});
```

and load these saved value at on create.
Hope you are getting some idea from this

**Edit: This is for your condition**

```
if(firstRun==false)//if running for first time 

      {
          SharedPreferences.Editor editor=settings.edit();
          editor.putBoolean("firstRun",true); 
          editor.commit();
          //execute your code for first time
      } 

      else 
      {     
 if(alldataSaved==false)
  {
         //stay in this activiy

   }
  else
{
 Intent iSubmit = new Intent(Registration_Form.this,Employee_List.class);
          startActivity(iSubmit);
          finish();
          //Default Activity startActivity(a); 
   }
   }
```

Comment: But How to come same Activity . I have already use shared prefs for always come second Activity after secondly start the app.

Comment: okay got your problem...do one thing put one other condition there like:
1)take one other sharedpref for checking whether all edittext value is saved in sharedpref.
2)if all values are not saved then stay in the same activity else not.

Comment: How to stay in this same activiy.

Comment: if you will not kill the activity (finish()) then it will stay on the same activity for sure

Comment: @  Kalpesh Lakhani : But How. I HAVE CHANGES LIKE THIS -

SharedPreferences settings=getSharedPreferences("prefs",0); 
boolean firstRun=settings.getBoolean("firstRun",false);
if(firstRun==false)//if running for first time 
{SharedPreferences.Editor editor=settings.edit();
editor.putBoolean("firstRun",true); 
editor.commit();
//execute your code for first time} 
else { if(alldataSaved == false){}else{Intent iSubmit =newIntent(Registration_Form.this,Employee_List.class);
startActivity(iSubmit);finish();startActivity(a); }}

Comment: et_Email_Id.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

      public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
          if(!hasFocus)
          {
            
     //do job here when Edittext lose focus 
            //means save value here
           edit.putString("Email_Id"+appWidgetId,et_Email_Id.getText().toString());
           edit.commit();
          }
      }
  });

Comment: @ Kalpesh Lakhani : Can you give me a some code lines.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use this

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

I hope thats work

Answer (score 0):

That's not how Android works. You cannot "restore" the same Activity in that fashion. What you CAN however do is save out the EditText content, for example in the onPause() or onStop() function, save out the contents of the EditTexts as Strings, put them in a List, then serialize that List out into a file. In the onResume() or onStart() method, deserialize this data from the file.

An example for such serialization is shown here, but I'll also paste it here:
[Put objects into bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24757410/put-objects-into-bundle/24757739#24757739)

Serialization:

```
private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try
    {
        out = openFileOutput("ModelBackup",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        try
        {
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
            oos.writeObject(list);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            Log.d(this.getClass().toString(), e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        Log.d(this.getClass().toString(), e.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            if(out != null) out.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            Log.d(this.getClass().toString(), e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Deserialization:

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    FileInputStream in = null;
    try
    {
        in = openFileInput("ModelBackup");
        ObjectInputStream oos = new ObjectInputStream(in);
        try
        {
            list = (List<String>)oos.readObject();
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            list = null;
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        Log.d(this.getClass().toString(), e.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            if(in != null) in.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If restarting an activity from a fragment, I would do it like so:

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {

         @Override
         public void run()
         {
            Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            getActivity().overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            getActivity().finish();

            getActivity().overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```