# How to pause the game on incoming call?

Tags: java, android

I have this quiz game and I need the game to pause when I get an incoming call, and to resume when I hang up. But what actually happens is that my game level quits and goes back to main menu. The same thing happens when I lock my phone (turn off the screen). I don't know what code to paste here cause I don't have any code regarding this issues, cause I thought this works automatically. I can paste my whole game class but it's pretty big. What to do?

EDIT:

I added this:

```
@override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
    }
```

But nothing. Also this:

```
@override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();   
    }
```

Comment: override `onPause()` method of Activity and pause the game

Comment: I did. Check my edited first post.

Comment: Are you also overriding `onResume()`? Read through the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

Comment: Yes. Check my first post.

Comment: You have to do some thing in `onPuase` mehod, just calling it's super wont pause the game for you! for example save the state of the game and stop it from continuing so when user came back, he does not loose anything.

Comment: that's not really "overriding" you're literally just calling the Activity implementation of `onPause()` and you're not doing anything specific to your own application that would pause your game logic..

Comment: So, if I have for example a countdown timer in my game, I have just to pause it on my onPause method and resume it on my onResume method?

Comment: But my activity closes after a phone call. Will this prevent that? Also, this thing happens also when I lock my screen, when I turn it off.

Comment: When the generated code says `//TODO`, it **usually** means there's *something you have to do*. Just because you called it's superclass doesn't fix your problem, or else you wouldn't be asking your question. I'm not sure how to answer your question, but I hope this guidance and advice helps you in future questions you may post on StackOverflow.

Comment: It's very simple.  You must assume that when your activity goes to the background, it might be destroyed and the next call will be onCreate().  Save your game state in onPause() and reload it to set the game back to where it was in onResume().  As others have said, you need to learn the Activity life cycle.

Comment: yes, yes you need to save the game state. This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24757410/put-objects-into-bundle/24757739#24757739

Answer (score 0):

When you Override the onPause()-Method, you have to actually do something to stop your game. For example if you have a loop to keep your game running like `while(running == true)` override your onPauseMethod to set `running` to `false`

Comment: while `while (running = true)` compiles, it's probably not what you mean. I think you mean `while (running == /*note the second =*/ true)`. Even better is `while (running)`

Comment: @stealthjong Just a typo. Fixed it. Thanks for the hint!